# How will Options on Micro E-mini S&P 500 futures be taxed in the US?

Tags: united-states, options, capital-gains-tax, futures

CME is going to publish a new contract: [Options on Micro E-mini S&P 500 Future](https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/equity-index/us-index/micro-e-mini-options.html) in Aug 31, 2020. I was wondering how will it be taxed?

There's already discussion like
[Are futures options eligible for the 60/40 tax rule?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/30298/are-futures-options-eligible-for-the-60-40-tax-rule) covering options trading tax, but this contract is different. As [section 1256](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p550/ch04.html#en_US_2013_publink100010326) says:

> Section 1256 Contract A section 1256 contract is any:
>
> Regulated futures: contract, Foreign currency contract, **Nonequity
> option**, Dealer equity option, or Dealer securities futures contract.
>
> Exceptions: A section 1256 contract does not include: Interest rate
> swaps, Currency swaps, Basis swaps, Interest rate caps, Interest rate
> floors, Commodity swaps, Equity swaps, Equity index swaps, Credit
> default swaps, or Similar agreements.

and the definition of Nonequity contracts:

> This is any listed option (defined later) that is not an equity
> option. Nonequity options include debt options, **commodity futures
> options**, currency options, and broad-based stock index options. A
> broad-based stock index is based on the value of a group of
> diversified stocks or securities (such as the Standard and Poor's 500
> index).
>
> Warrants based on a stock index that are economically, substantially
> identical in all material respects to options based on a stock index
> are treated as options based on a stock index.

But this option is not a commodity futures option. I was wondering how will it be treated in tax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that options have already long been traded on the regular and E-mini S&P 500 futures. The Micro E-mini options will be similar.

The key to answering the question is that all of these options **are** commodity futures options. Don't read "commodity futures" as referring only to physically settled contracts on tangible goods like oil and wheat. In the US, the *Commodity Futures* Trading Commission (CFTC) regulates financial futures on broad-based indexes as well as futures on tangible commodities. According to the [CFTC](https://www.cftc.gov/IndustryOversight/ContractsProducts/SecurityFuturesProduct/sfpoverview.html):

> futures on broad-based security indexes are under the exclusive jurisdiction of the CFTC.

S&P 500 futures options are commodity futures options, and thus are nonequity options, and thus are Section 1256 contracts.